# c18 coding advice / braces error / function declaration help

Tags: pic, adc, c, mplab

I have almost NO experience coding so please excuse the crude style and verbose commenting.  I am trying to sample from 4 sensors (1 every 15 minutes). I thought it would be more efficient to have the `delay` and `data_write` functions as separate functions to call but that's just not working out very well. I consistently get the following error:

> Error [1302] old style function declarations not supported

at the end of the `data_write` function no matter where or how I put the braces (nested, same line, eliminate, etc.) `delay` function doesn't give the error whether it's before or after the `data_write` function.

Please feel free to recommend a better layout for me. Also, I really don't have any understanding of the data memory so this routine is probably crap, I know. It's strangely not giving me any errors though so I'll not look that gift horse in the mouth just yet.

=====================================

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <p18f452.h>
    #include <delays.h>
    #include <adc.h>

    int result;                         // used in ADC result handling
    int i;                              // used in delay loop/function
    int data_adr=0x64;                  // used in data_write function. initial=d100

    // assuming 4MHz oscillator => 8fosc.   Tinst= (4)*Tosc = (4)*(250ns) = 1us
    // all 4 sensors should read every minute so each will begin sequentially,
    // after 15sec delay from previous ADC conversion completes.

    void delay (void);                 // delay function prototype declaration
    void data_write (int, int);             // data-write function prototype declaration

    main()
    {
    // I think I need a while (1) loop here to repeat the loop forever???

    // sensor 1 configured to port AN0
        OpenADC(ADC_FOSC_8 & ADC_RIGHT_JUST & ADC_5ANA_0REF, ADC_CH0 & ADC_INT_OFF);
                            //configures ADC for port AN0 = sensor 1 input
            delay();                    // call the delay function
            ConvertADC();               // initiate conversion of sensor1 @ AN0
            while(BusyADC());           // waiting to complete conversion
            result=ReadADC();           // read the result of sensor1 @ AN0
            data_write();               // call data_write function
        CloseADC();


    // sensor 2 configured to port AN1
        OpenADC(ADC_FOSC_8 & ADC_RIGHT_JUST & ADC_5ANA_0REF, ADC_CH1 & ADC_INT_OFF);
                            //configures ADC for port AN1 = sensor 2 input
           delay();
           ConvertADC();
           while(BusyADC());
           result=ReadADC();
           data_write ();
        CloseADC();

    // sensor 3 configured to port AN2
        OpenADC(ADC_FOSC_8 & ADC_RIGHT_JUST & ADC_5ANA_0REF, ADC_CH2 & ADC_INT_OFF);
                            //configures ADC for port AN2 = sensor 3 input
           delay();
           ConvertADC();
           while(BusyADC());
           result=ReadADC();
           data_write ();
        CloseADC();

    // sensor 4 configured to port AN3
        OpenADC(ADC_FOSC_8 & ADC_RIGHT_JUST & ADC_5ANA_0REF, ADC_CH3 & ADC_INT_OFF);
                            //configures ADC for port AN3 = sensor 4 input
           delay();
           ConvertADC();
           while(BusyADC());
           result=ReadADC();
           data_write ();
        CloseADC();

        return (result);
    }

    // Delay function sequence
    void delay (void)
    {                                       // 15second delay routine
                                    // 15sec/Tinst= 15sec/1us
                                    // = 15*10^6 Tinst = 10K * 1500
                                    // Delay10KTCYx(1)= 0.01sec
                                    // = (10K)*(250)*(6)
        i=6;
        while(i>0) {
           Delay10KTCYx(250);      // 2.5sec delay
            i=i--;                  // run 6 times for total 15sec delay loop
        }
        return;
    }

    // data write sequence
    void data_write (data_adr, result) {
         _asm
         movlw  data_adr        // starting data memory address = data_adr
         movwf  EEADR,A
         movlw  result              // gets data stored in "result" variable
         movwf  EEDATA,A            // places data into data memory holder
         bcf    EECON1,EEPGD,A      // points to data memory
         bcf    EECON1,CFGS,A       // access data eeprom
         bsf    EECON1,WREN,A       // enable write to data EEPROM
         bcf    INTCON,IE,A         // disable interrupt
         movlw  0x55                // start flash erase sequence
         movwf  EECON2,A
         movlw  0xAA
         movwf  EECON2,A            // end flash erase sequence
         bsf    EECONN1,WR,A        // enable bit to start the write operation
         bsf    INTCON,GIE,A        // re-enable interrupt
         bcf    EECON1,WREN         // restores the write command to =disabled
         _endasm

         data_adr = data_adr+2;
         if (data_adr >= 0xC6)      // if address >= d'198
             data_adr = 0x64;       // resets starting point to d'100

        return; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the other answers have good points, and point out other problems, but the **specific** reason you're getting the error `old style function declarations not supported` is because your `data_write` function declaration is missing the types.  It needs to be changed from

```
void data_write (data_adr, result)
```

to

```
void data_write (int data_adr, int result)
```

Comment: I have another question about a specific part of this code, the data_write function actually (with assembly).  I assume I should ask it as a new question rather than keep reposting similar code blocks?

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of the return in main function. To where are you going to return the data? There's no operating system and return is meaningless, so it could be source of some problems.

How exactly are you going to output the data? Looks like you're trying to write to data memory, but what are you going to do after that, remove the chip and physically read the EEPROM using a programmer?

Next, yes you do need while (1) to keep looping properly around the function. You may get some sort of looping even without while. If I remember correctly, PIC18 flash is by default filled with NOPs. It will keep executing instructions until the end of address space is reached after which it should (again if I remember correctly) wrap around and get back to first instruction. You should not rely on this feature and should instead wrap contents of main with while (1) or equivalent.

Next, the errors themselves: Well, the compiler manual states that it's not related to braces at all. It's related to function declaration style. You actually need to write the type of the variable and name when declaring a function. What you've created are variables with same name as global variables. When your code is in function, it won't use global variables. Instead it will use local variables with that name which will mask global variables.

Also you're calling functions badly. You need to actually list the arguments when you call functions!

Next, in C18 prototype for main needs to be void main (void), which goes well with the no return rule I mentioned before.

You also seem to call register names incorrectly. Try actually reading in the user manual how C18 call each register in the PIC and how to address each individual bit of a register. For example, you'd use `INTCON1bits.GIE` to access the general interrupt enable bit in the interrupt control register one.

Another thing I've noticed is that you use int for loop counter. Don't do that if you can avoid it. Try to use chars as much as possible since they're the MCU's native data type. Ints will take longer to process and will result in slower than expected loops.

Also you mentioned functions and efficiency. Keep in mind that C18 can't do function in-lining, so if you ever have the need to efficiently call a function, you're going to have to replace it with a macro.

Comment: AndrejaKo,
Thanks for the reply.  I thought that since the main function was needing to pass "result" to the data_write function, I had to declare it that way.  If I leave out the return, will the data_write function still have access to the "result" variable?

The data is supposed to be sort-of simply logged.  My plan was to retrieve through ICSP or similar.  That part's not super important for me.

Since the compiler error stops at the closing brace and specifies it's a K&R formatting issue, I thought that.

I think I understand the global variables issue.  I'll rename.

Comment: sorry about my formatting here, too.  I'm not used to it either.

Comment: Also, the format for addressing those bits is straight from my textbook (Huang -Pic microcontrollers)  
I see your point and have done that before with port bits so I can change that too, no problem.  

I was just trying to be slick and call functions rather than cut/paste the same code inside main.  Thanks for the input.  :-D

Comment: @Mark Well to me it looks like you need to learn a bit of C before trying to program microcontrollers in C. Take a look at [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson4.html) tutorial for example. Basically, return is used to provide results of a function to the function which called it.

Comment: Thank you AdrejaKo.  I appreciate your patience.  I'm actually taking the class now but the instructor doesn't give many examples and seems to assume we're all programmers.  This course is not supposed to require programming experience though.  I'm sorry for the basic questions.

Answer (score 1):

As Andreja points out, you are not using the return statement correctly.
Also, now the actual error message has been edited in, it makes it clear the error related to your `data_write` is due to not declaring the argument types as Jim states in his answer. You can see examples of how they should be declared in the code below.

The `return` statement is used to pass a result back to the caller, of a certain type dictated by the function definition.

For example, this function returns an int:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

To use the above, you do something like:

```
int result;
result = add(5, 6); // result = 11
```

But this function doesn't accept any arguments or return anything (note the `void` return/argument type):

```
void do_something(void)
{
    // do something here...
    //
}
```

There are many uses for a function with no return/arguments - for example, setting up a peripheral, initalising memory, etc.

Another way of getting information back from a function is to use a pointer passed as an argument:

```
void add(int a, int b, int* p_result)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a + b;
    *p_result = temp;
}
```

To use the above, we pass the address of the result variable as the 3rd argument (the `&` operator):

```
int result = 0;
int a = 6;
int b = 5;
add(a, b, &result); // result will equal 11 on function return
```

So hopefully you can see there is no use to have a `return` statement for a function declared as `void`, (unless you wish to return early as part of some decision logic - similar to `continue` and `break` statements, which you don't have in your functions above) If you wish to return something, declare the type at the start of the function definition.
As Andreja suggests, I would do some reading on the basics C functions and pointers.

Comment: Thank you Oli,  That's very helpful.  You are right, I was confused about the main.  I meant to put something like 
    int main ()
thinking the return would pass the "result" out of main, to the "data-write" function.  I have a LOT to learn.